# Generic method convertible to structural type in scala

Tags: generics, scala

Why can't I do this:

```
def compare[A <% { def toInt: Int }, 
            B <% { def toInt: Int }]
           (bs: Seq[A], is: Seq[B]): Boolean = { 
  bs.toArray.zip(is) forall { p => p._1.toInt == p._2.toInt } 
}
```

In order to compare any Sequence of types convertible to `Int`? How can I implement a similar pattern?

---

Update: this should run `Message.compare(List(1.0, 2.0, 3.0), List(0, 0, 0))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good example of where the problem lies would seem to be doing this:

```
val a = implicitly[Int => { def toInt : Int }]
a(1).toInt
```

Scala 2.9.1 blows up at this point sometime in Runtime code - I can only think that this is a bug.

You can achieve the effect you're looking for using type classes, though: the following code works in all of your examples:

```
def compare[A : Numeric, B : Numeric](bs : Seq[A], cs : Seq[B]) = {
  (bs, cs).zipped.forall(implicitly[Numeric[A]].toInt(_) == implicitly[Numeric[B]].toInt(_))
}
```

This should also have the benefit of being faster than the version using structural types. If you need to add your own types in that should be convertible to integers, you can provide evidence for the Numeric typeclass in the same way as is done at https://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/browser/scala/tags/R_2_9_1_final/src//library/scala/math/Numeric.scala#L1 for the standard values.

Answer (score 9):

Since you're dealing with `Array`s, you need `ClassManifest`s.

```
def compare[A <% { def toInt: Int } : ClassManifest, 
            B <% { def toInt: Int } : ClassManifest]
            (bs: Seq[A], is: Seq[B]): Boolean = { 
  (bs.toArray, is).zipped.forall(_.toInt == _.toInt)
}
```

The compiler error message in this case couldn't be clearer IMO.

**EDIT:**

You don't really need to convert sequences to arrays. The following works just fine.

```
def compare[A <% { def toInt: Int }, 
            B <% { def toInt: Int }]
           (bs: Seq[A], is: Seq[B]): Boolean = { 
      (bs, is).zipped.forall(_.toInt == _.toInt)
}
```

Comment: Strange... This fails: `println(Message.compare(List(1, 2, 3), List(0, 0, 0)))`

Comment: @HugoSFerreira: That is indeed strange. I am sorry; I do not know how to get around this.

Comment: @HugoSFerreira: [It appears to be a bug.](https://twitter.com/#!/milessabin/status/144805669772595200)

Answer (score 2):

It works fine for me when I remove the unnecessary `toArray`

```
def compare[A <% { def toInt: Int }, B <% { def toInt: Int }](bs: Seq[A], is: Seq[B]): Boolean = { bs.zip(is) forall { p => p._1.toInt == p._2.toInt } }
Class A{def toInt = 4}
Class B(i: Int) {def toInt = i}
compare (List(new A, new A), List(new B(3), new B(4))) //false
compare (List(new A, new A), List(new B(4), new B(4))) //true
```

Converting the Seq to an array would require you add an implicit ClassManifest, however Scala does not let you mix those with view bounds.

Comment: It fails with `compare (List(2, 3), List(2, 4))`

Comment: Well the view bounds you're setting say that types A and B must be classes that have an implicit conversion available to a structural type with a method `toInt`.  2, 3 etc. are integers, and Scala's Int class has no `toInt` method.  In order to get that to work, you'd need to define a class that's basically what my example class B is, then create an implicit conversion function from Int to B.

Comment: `implicitly[Int => { def toInt: Int }]` succeeds. So the code compiles, but fails at runtime.

Comment: "however Scala does not let you mix those with view bounds." << It does, thought that's not a solution to OP's problem.